# PHP Upload de arquivos para um diretório criado com mkdir

Tags: php, html, upload, mkdir

Tenho um formulário HTML onde recebo arquivos por upload, no caso um de imagem e outro com vários arquivos em PDF, preciso organiza-los colocando tudo em uma pasta, para isso utilizei o mkdir, consegui criar uma pasta com o nome que recebo de uma variável, ou seja o nome da pasta que está sendo criada é uma variável que pega conteúdo via POST de um input do formulário, como faço para jogar os arquivos vindo do upload dentro dessa pasta que está sendo criada no mesmo código?

O que está acontecendo no momento com o meu código atual é: os arquivos são colocados no mesmo lugar onde a pasta é criada mas não consigo coloca-los dentro dela.

Código PHP:

```
$vregistro = utf8_decode($_POST['f_registro']); //Guarda um nome digitado pelo usuário que será o nome da pasta criada

mkdir("C:\local\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos/$vregistro", 0777, true);  //Cria a pasta no servidor com o nome guardado na variável



$uploaddir = 'C:\local\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos/';           //Arquivo fica no mesmo local da pasta criada porém fora dela
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fanexo']['name']);              

echo '<pre>';                                                                

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fanexo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {                   //Upload de imagem que precisa ser guardado na pasta criada acima
    echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";

}else{ 

    echo "Upload ERROR <--\n";

}

echo 'Debug: ';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";




$total = count($_FILES['pdfanexo']['name']);

for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {                                      //Upload de vários PDFS que precisa ser guardados na mesma pasta que a imagem no caso a pasta criada no inicio
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['pdfanexo']['tmp_name'][$i];

    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $newFilePath = "C:\local\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos/" . $_FILES['pdfanexo']['name'][$i];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: é só pegar o nome da pasta que criou e colocar no caminho `$uploaddir = 'C:\local\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos/'.$vregistro;`

Comment: Fazendo isso ele continua da mesma forma, só coloca o nome que está guardado na $vregistro nos arquivos do upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom olhando por cima reescrevi parte do código.

```
<?php
$vregistro = utf8_decode($_POST['f_registro']); //Guarda um nome digitado pelo usuário que será o nome da pasta criada
$diretorioBase = 'C:\local\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos\\';
$fullPath=rtrim($diretorioBase.$vregistro,'\\/').'/';
if (!@mkdir($fullPath, 0777, true) && !is_dir($diretorioBase.$vregistro)) {

    $uploadfile = $fullPath.basename($_FILES['fanexo']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['fanexo']['tmp_name'],
        $uploadfile
    )) {                   //Upload de imagem que precisa ser guardado na pasta criada acima
        echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Upload ERROR <--\n";
    }
    echo 'Debug: ';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
    $total = count($_FILES['pdfanexo']['name']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {                                      //Upload de vários PDFS que precisa ser guardados na mesma pasta que a imagem no caso a pasta criada no inicio
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['pdfanexo']['tmp_name'][$i];
        if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
            $newFilePath = $fullPath.$tmpFilePath;
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {


            }
        }
    }
}
```

repare o uso de `$fullPath=rtrim($diretorioBase.$vregistro,'\\/').'\\';` assim eu garanto que termine com uma \ no final. o principal erro no seu código e na hora de gerar o `$newFilePath`, neste ponto você não esta gerando o nome do diretório, assim temos:

DE:

```
$newFilePath = "C:\local\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos/" . $_FILES['pdfanexo']['name'][$i];
```

PARA:

```
$newFilePath = "C:\local\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos/$vregistro/" . $_FILES['pdfanexo']['name'][$i];
```

Repare que o meu código esta diferente, com esta modificação o seu já deve se tornar funcional, repare apenas que termino o PATH com uma / o uso de \ também resulta na separação de diretório no windows, caso queira um código mais legível e que funcione tanto em windows como em unix like, use a constante `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` no lugar de qualquer `/` ou `\` .

Comment: Então, estive tentando fazer isso mas quando faço a alteração a pasta continua sendo criada porém não é feito o upload dos arquivos, não aparece nenhum erro só simplesmente não faz o upload.

Comment: não tem algum log, alguma coisa para vermos algum ponto para explorar? sem esse tipo de informação não podemos ajudar você

Comment: Fiz uma alteração aqui e consegui fazer funcionar muito obrigado pela ajuda está funcionando tudo certo agora.

Comment: Diga o que aconteceu, pode ser que ajuda outros passando pelo mesmo.

Comment: Bom basicamente o que faltava era indicar nos diretórios que "$vregistro" era uma variável, o que fiz foi fazer o mkdir dessa forma: " 
 '..\..\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos/'.$vregistro " e quando fosse fazer o upload para dentro dessa pasta: " '..\..\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos/' .$vregistro. '/' ".

Comment: entendi, outra forma para você representar ` "..\..\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos/{$vregistro}/ "`, haha fica mais legível na minha opinião

Comment: Se perceber é o que faço nesse ponto

`$diretorioBase = 'C:\local\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos\\';`
`$fullPath=rtrim($diretorioBase.$vregistro,'\\/').'/';`

Comment: É preciso dar uma estudada melhor no PHP estou iniciando ainda, então deixo passar algumas coisas só por estarem expressas de outra maneira. =/